# .TargetPath doesn't seem to take Variables?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm trying to create a Shortcut to a Folder using the Powershell ISE, and appareantly, opposed to all examples I've found, `$Shortcut.TargetPath` does not seem to want to be assigned a variable, or interact with one.

I've attempted to use literal Paths in Quotation Marks (`$Shortcut.TargetPath = "\\thisis\where\the\path\goes\"`), which seem to work, however as soon as I use a variable it simply turns to a null `($Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetDir)`.

I've tried to add it, I've tried to write a value first with quotation marks and then overwrite that value, I've tried to write a value with quotation marks and then add to that value, it always turns to null.

```
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

$TargetDir = "D:\Files\"
$SourceDir = "C:\Windows\"

$Shortcutid1 = $TargetDir + '.lnk'
$Shortcutid = $SourceDir + '.lnk'

$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($Shortcutid1)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetDir
$Shortcut.TargetPath
$TargetDir

$Shortcut1 = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($Shortcutid)
$Shortcut1.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\"
$Shortcut1.TargetPath
```

Now, what I'd excpect to happen, would be this:

```
D:\Files\
D:\Files\
C:\Windows\
```

Instead, I get the output:

```
D:\Files\
C:\Windows\
```

The line of `$Shortcut.TargetPath` is just empty, but not null.

I tested it with `if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Shortcut.TargetPath)) {"empty"} else {"wat"}`, and it the output is `wat`, so weirdly enough, there seems to at least be something in there?
Edit: Powershell Version is Version 5.1.17763.503

Comment: What Powershell version do you use? I get exactly your expected output with your example...

Comment: same goes for me. i tested it on the ise and got the same expected output

Comment: I am using Version 5.1.17763.503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. You need to put quotation marks around the variable as well. Example:

```
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

$TargetDir = "D:\Files\"
$SourceDir = "C:\Windows\"

$Shortcutid1 = $TargetDir + '.lnk'
$Shortcutid = $SourceDir + '.lnk'

$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($Shortcutid1)
```

**`$Shortcut.TargetPath = "$TargetDir"`**

```
$Shortcut.TargetPath
$TargetDir

$Shortcut1 = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($Shortcutid)
$Shortcut1.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\"
$Shortcut1.TargetPath
```

Expected output matches the actual output this time. '' Appareantly ignores Variables if you're into posting $ in your code. "" however allows variables to be recognised.
If you want to add more variables I'd recommend merging them beforehand Example:

**`$a = "$TargetDir" + "\yourfolder"`**
**`$Shortcut.TargetPath = "$a"`**

Leads to an output of:

```
D:\Files\yourfolder
D:\Files\
C:\Windows
```